# Conditional expectation of the product of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be random variables, with $A$ and $B$ dependent. Is it true that

$\mathbb{E}(A\cdot B|C)=\mathbb{E}(A|C)\cdot\mathbb{E}(B|A,C)$?

In particular, can I say that \begin{equation*}\mathbb{E}(A\cdot B|C)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(A\cdot B|A,C)|C)=\mathbb{E}(A\cdot\mathbb{E}( B|A,C)|C)=\mathbb{E}(A|C)\cdot\mathbb{E}(B|A,C)?
\end{equation*}Here I have used the following two properties of the conditional expectation:

1. $\mathbb{E}(A\cdot B|F)=A\cdot\mathbb{E}(B|F)$ if $A$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra F
2. $\mathbb{E}(X|G)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|F)|G)$ if $G\subset F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

If this is not true, under which conditions is it true and what can one say in general about the conditional expectation of the product of two dependent random variables?

Thank you!

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are independent then it is true. But then $E(B\mid A,C) = E(B\mid C)$. Apart from that I fear it is quite a broad question and that may have been the reason for the downvote?

Comment: What your $E(B|A,C)$ means? Is it $E(B|A,C)=P(B|(AC))$?

Comment: May be your $A,B,C$ are random variables, I am sorry to confuse it as random events in  my above comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are random variables.

Comment: I have now added more details to my question and my attempt to answer. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathsf{E}[A|C]\ne0$ a.s., then $\mathsf{E}[A\cdot B|C]=\mathsf{E}[A|C] \mathsf{E}[B|A,C]$ if and only if  $\mathsf{E}[B|A,C]=\mathsf{E}[B|C]$. A sufficient condition of $\mathsf{E}[A\cdot B|C]=\mathsf{E}[A|C] \mathsf{E}[B|A,C]$ is $B\underset{C}{\perp\!\!\perp}A$, i.e. $B$ and $A$ are conditionally independent given $C$(c.f. O. Kallenberg, *Foundations of modern Probability*, p.109--).